# text transform in datatable

Tags: c#

In CSS, we can use text-transform: capitalize; to make every first letter capital. 
I have a data table and i want to make every first letter in each column capitalize. how can i perform text-transformation : capitalize to sql datatables? (am using c# as code behind)
Here is my code..

```
public void myfunction(DataSet ds)
{
    DataTable myTable = ds.Tables[0];
    // and now have to transform each first letter capital for 
    // all the columns in this table..
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about using [`string.ToUpper()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewdd6aed.aspx)?

Comment: It will transform the whole word in upper.. while i want only first letter capitalized.

Comment: Be creative! If you really do not know how to make one character in a string to upper case, I would strongly recommend reading a beginner's book on C#/.NET programming.

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop all `DataRows`:

```
foreach(DataRow r in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    foreach(DataColumn c in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
    {
        if(!r.IsNull(c))
        {
            var field = r[c].ToString().Trim();
            if (field.Length == 1)
                r[c] = field.ToUpper();
            else
                r[c] = char.ToUpper(field[0]) + field.Substring(1);
        }
    }
}
```

But the best approach would be to do it in dbms.

```
UPPER(substring(Column1,1,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var column in myTable.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>())
{
    string name = column.ColumnName;

    char[] chars = name.ToCharArray();
    chars[0] = char.ToUpper(chars[0]);

    column.ColumnName = new string(chars);
}
```

Another option:

```
 string name = column.ColumnName;
 column.ColumnName =  char.ToUpper(name.First()) 
                              + new string(name.Skip(1).ToArray());
```

Comment: I assume OP wants to uppercase the first letter of all fields in the DataTable, not the column-names.

Comment: You are capitalizing the column names. I would guess he wants the row _values_ instead.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: *i want to make every first letter in each column capitalize*, not each row

Comment: @UweKeim: even the comment: and now have to transform each first letter capital for 
    // all the columns in this table..

Comment: @CuongLe: people often speak of columns when they actually mean fields. Otherwise he would have spoken of `ColumnNames` exlicitely(imho).

Comment: @CuongLe Don't try to argue with Germanys ;-) We seem to tend to be nitpickers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string ToCamelCase(string input)
{
    string output = string.Empty;
    foreach (string word in input.Split(' '))
        output += word[0].ToString().ToUpper() + word.Substring(1) + " ";
    return output.Trim();
}
```

Comment: It may work, but i have nearly 100 no of tables and so thousands nos of columns, so it will take too long to transform this way..

Answer (score 0):

you can try with

```
foreach(var column in YourDataTable.Columns)
{
   var result = UppercaseFirst(column.ColumnName);
   Console.WriteLine(result);

   column.ColumnName = result;
}
```

Method

```
public string UppercaseFirst(string s)
{
    // Check for empty string.
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    // Return char and concat substring.
    return char.ToUpper(s[0]) + s.Substring(1);
}
```

Comment: You are ignoring the result of your `UppercaseFirst` method call.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the question

```
foreach (DataColumn column in myTable.Columns)
{
    column.ColumnName=UppercaseFirst(column.ColumnName);
}

static string UppercaseFirst(string s){
    // Check for empty string.
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    // Return char and concat substring.
    return char.ToUpper(s[0]) + s.Substring(1);
}
```

With UppercaseFirst courtesy of [DotNetPerls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/uppercase-first-letter)